# Tengo problema al convertir una lista a dataset

Tags: c#, webservice, lista

lo que tengo pensado hacer es que en mi web service tengo el siguiente codigo de abajo, quiero mostrar lo que tengo en mi List<>

```
[WebMethod]
        public string EstatusPublic(int index)
        {
            DataSet data;
            List<EstPub> lst = new List<EstPub>();
            var gdt = new Google.DataTable.Net.Wrapper.DataTable();
            data = gr.MetEstatus(index);
            lst = (from DataRow dr in data.Tables[0].Rows
                     select new EstPub()
                     {
                         Estatus = Convert.ToString(dr["Estatus"]),
                         Cantidad = Convert.ToInt32(dr["cont"])
                     }).ToList();
            gdt.AddColumn(new Column(ColumnType.String, "Estatus", "Estatus"));
            gdt.AddColumn(new Column(ColumnType.Number, "Cantidad", "Cantidad"));

            foreach (var item in lst)
            {
                Row r = gdt.NewRow();
                r.AddCellRange(new Cell[]
                {
                    new Cell(item.Estatus),
                    new Cell(item.Cantidad)
                });
                gdt.AddRow(r);
            }
            return gdt.GetJson();
        }


public class EstPub
{
    public string Estatus { get; set; }
    public int Cantidad { get; set; }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Me sale lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui tengo la lista, no se si es correcto manejar el List<> o tendria que utilizar otro tipo para mi metodo. Lo que digo es que esta lista obtiene los datos en mi variable --preg-- y lo retorna.
Les pido de su ayuda para ver si me pueden ayudar con una solucion gracias,

```
public static List<EstPub> MetEstatus(int index)
        {
            List<EstPub> preg = new List<EstPub>();
            DataClassesDataContext dcdc = new DataClassesDataContext();

            preg = (from p in dcdc.Publicacion
                    join e in dcdc.estatus_publicacion on p.id_est_publicacion equals e.id_est_publicacion
                    where p.fecha_inicio_publicacion.Month == 2 && p.fecha_inicio_publicacion.Year == 2020
                    group e by e.nom_publicacion into gr
                    where gr.Count() > 1
                    select new EstPub()
                    {
                        Estatus = gr.Key,
                        Cantidad = gr.Count()
                    }).ToList();
            return preg;
        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: porque asignas la respuesta de MetEstatus() a un DataSet ? si la respuesta es un List<EstPub>

Comment: No buscaba como mandar mi lista en mi WebMethod y queria saber si podia mandarlo como DataSet

Comment: no se envia nada como dataset, serializa la clase a json directamente, te ahorras varios pasos, usando la libreria de json.net

Comment: Si lo apliqué como me mostraste

Answer (score 0):

Si estas exponiendo un `WebMethod` no necesitas de ningun `DataSet` para serializar, se puede retornar una `List<>` directamente.

Por otro lado los `WebMethod` se definin como `static`, sino no funcionan

Podrias simplemente hacer

```
[WebMethod]
public string EstatusPublic(int index)
{
    List<EstPub> data = Graficos.MetEstatus(index);

    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
}
```

`MetEstatus()` lo defines como `static`, por lo tanto no necesitas de una instancia de la clase para acceder a ese metodo

Usas la libreria

[Newtonsoft.Json nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/)

para serializar la lista a string

Comment: El metodo que tengo de tipo List<> , si podria pasarlo a mi webmethod para que me devuelva el valor de formato json?

Comment: Cuando ejecute el web servive no me apareció ningún webmethod , lo puse como public static string

Comment: no aparecio? sino tiene que aparecer nada, es un webmethod no un web service, no hay wsdl o descriptor SOAP del servicio como para que tenga que aparecer nada. Solo lo invocas usando tools como ser PostMan o sino desde codigo usando HttpClient desde codigo c# o $.ajax de jquery si es codigo javascript

Comment: Para saber si me está mandando los datos lo invoco de esa manera?

Comment: de que manera? no queda claro

Comment: Es que estoy trabajando con un web service, para que lo datos que obtenia ya los pueda ver en mi pagina, yo entendi que con el $.ajax yo podia llamar o hacer uso de ese webmethod

Comment: pero entonces tienes un asmx ? si es asi en ese caso entonces no debe ir el static

Comment: Si es un asmx el que utilizo

Comment: ok, entonces quita el static, pense que era un webmethod en un aspx, pero despues el resto serializa a json directo la lista, no necesitas ningun dataset

Comment: Si me lo mostró, pero igual lo que hice fue poner lo que tengo en el metodo List<> lo pase en mi WebMethod del asmx. y asi si me muestra lo que optiene la lista. Ahorita lo muestro

Answer (score 0):

Si se resolvio, gracias.

Este es mi Webmethod

```
[WebMethod]
        public List<EstPub> EstatusPublic(int index)
        {
            List<EstPub> preg = new List<EstPub>();
            DataClassesDataContext dcdc = new DataClassesDataContext();

            preg = (from p in dcdc.Publicacion
                    join e in dcdc.estatus_publicacion on p.id_est_publicacion equals e.id_est_publicacion
                    where p.fecha_inicio_publicacion.Month == 2 && p.fecha_inicio_publicacion.Year == 2020
                    group e by e.nom_publicacion into gr
                    where gr.Count() > 1
                    select new EstPub()
                    {
                        Estatus = gr.Key,
                        Cantidad = gr.Count()
                    }).ToList();
            return preg;

        }
```

Y este es el resultado
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora si mira, esta con formato json como lo esta mandando. con `data` obtengo lo que esta en el metodo `Graficos.MetEstatus()`
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    [WebMethod]
            public string EstatusPublic()
            {
                List<EstPub> data = Graficos.MetEstatus();
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
            }
```

El metodo `List`

```
public static List<EstPub> MetEstatus()
        {
            List<EstPub> preg = new List<EstPub>();
            DataClassesDataContext dcdc = new DataClassesDataContext();

            preg = (from p in dcdc.Publicacion
                    join e in dcdc.estatus_publicacion on p.id_est_publicacion equals e.id_est_publicacion
                    where p.fecha_inicio_publicacion.Month == 2 && p.fecha_inicio_publicacion.Year == 2020
                    group e by e.nom_publicacion into gr
                    where gr.Count() > 1
                    select new EstPub()
                    {
                        Estatus = gr.Key,
                        Cantidad = gr.Count()
                    }).ToList();
            return preg;
        }
```

Comment: si dejas ese codigo en `Graficos.MetEstatus()` funciona igual, no tenias que usar `gr` porque `MetEstatus()` lo defines como `static`, usas el nombre de la clase `Graficos`. Tal cual como lo mencione en la respuesta

Comment: ademas se suponia que retornabas un `json`, por eso usaste `GetJson()` en cambio la respuesta que tienes ahora es un `xml`

Comment: Si logre que lo mande en formato json, utilice lo que me habias comentado anteriormente. Hay muestro mi respuesta con el resultado. si es correcto como lo apliqué?